# CUPS and broadcast on Wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, cups, broadcast

My CUPS server (Debian 10) propagates its shared printers on the switch it is connected to, to the PCs (Debian 9 & 10) connected to that same switch.

On the other hand, the propagation is not done at Wifi terminals offering the same subnet as the one used by the PCs or the CUPS server.
The DHCP service is the same for the switches and the Wifi (for information).

Is the broadcast used by CUPS blocked if a parameter of the bridge to Wifi is not activated?
(I control the DHCP server but I don't control these switches and the wifi bridge, so before calling the provider, I look for information)

Any idea, track, link are welcome!

Comment: Your configuration may rely on host names instead of IP addresses, which may be done with Zeroconf. Some routers may be configured by default to block Zeroconf - and especially if you have an Android device as DHCP server, it blocks it too.

Comment: Thanks @rexkogitans, I will check this with my network manager.
Is it possible that if the Multicast is blocked on WiFi, I don't receive the shares on WiFi, but on the Switches that would allow it.
And that Zeroconf does not pass on the Switches nor on the WiFi and therefore I cannot print to the cups because I only have its IP but the printing would use the local name that you indicate?

Comment: yes, this is possible if the route does not pass the AP but only the switch. So, if both device A and the cups server are connected to the switch, then device A may see the cups server's shares. However, device B in the WiFi part of the network won't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WORKAROUND Broadcasting Network Problem :

The Network Manager and Wifi provider seems to not be able to autorize the broadcast needed.
But I've found with the `BrowsePoll` option a solution that permit to the client to receive immediately shared printers from central CUPS server.

On client Computer, I've added in /etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf

`BrowsePoll <IP of CUPS Server>`

Then restart cupsd & cups-browsed services.
Instantly received the shared printers.

So, for now it remains for me the most important problem : [Does CUPS act as a proxy or can it with certain configurations and types of printer connections?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/606175)